# Why docker java app is getting killed because of memory?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, memory, amazon-ecs

**Problem**: application is killed due to memory usage

```
  Status reason OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage
  Exit Code 137
```

**Environment**: Spring Boot app in docker container on AWS ECS instance with configuration:

- AWS hard memory limit/total RAM - 384 MB
- -Xmx134m
- -Xms134m
- -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=110m

According to the java max memory formula (which I have found during the weeks of research -https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-my-java-process and improved a bit):

> *max_memory* = xmx + non-heap_memory + threads_number * xss
>
> *non-heap_memory* = metaspace + (compressed_class_space + codeHeap_profiledmethods + CodeHeap_non-methods+ CodeHeap_non-profiled_methods).

Take into account that 2nd part of non-heap memory takes nearly 40mb combined

so in my case `max_memory = 134(xmx) + 110(metaspace_max) + 40(non-heap-not_metaspace) + 9(threads) * 1(default Xss) = 293`

However, under the load heapUsedMemory = ~105-120mb and non-heapUsedMemory(metaspace + JVM stuff) = ~140mb which means that there must be 384 - 120 - 140 = 124 mb of *free memory*.
So the problem is that there is plenty of free memory and all java tools are showing it(jstat -gc, Spring on grafana, different java API etc).
Here is code-snippet of an API I have developed and used during my research:

```
    @GetMapping("/memory/info")
public Map<String, String> getMmUsage() {
    Map<String, Long> info = new HashMap<>();
    List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memPool = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
    for (MemoryPoolMXBean p : memPool) {
        if ("Metaspace".equals(p.getName())) {
            info.put("metaspaceMax", p.getUsage().getMax());
            info.put("metaspaceCommitted", p.getUsage().getCommitted());
            info.put("metaspaceUsed", p.getUsage().getUsed());
        }
    }

    info.put("heapMax", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax());
    info.put("heapCommitted", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted());
    info.put("heapUsed", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed());
    info.put("non-heapMax", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getMax());
    info.put("non-heapCommitted", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted());
    info.put("non-heapUsed", ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed());

    Map<String, String> memoryData = info.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> {
        long kb = e.getValue() / 1024;
        return (kb / 1024) + " Mb (" + kb + " Kb)";
    }, (v1, v2) -> v1, TreeMap::new));

    Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    memoryData.put("threadsCount", Integer.toString(threads.size()));
    memoryData.put("threadsCountRunning",
            Long.toString(threads.stream().filter(t -> t.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE).count()));

    return memoryData;
}
```

So my application should be stable since it has a lot of memory to deal with. But its not the case. As I described above `Container killed due to memory usage`

As I described above java tools shows that there are plenty of memory and that memory(heap) is being released. On the other hand AWS cloudwatch metric MmeoryUtilization show constant growth of memory (in very small portions):
[image: aws cloudwatch metric]

**Interesting exploration**: during endless testing I have found next: when I set xmx=134MB application lives longer and was capable of surviving 5 rounds of performance tests, when I set xmx/xms = 200mb it survived 1 round of performance tests. How could this be possible??

**My opinion**: It looks like that there is something that uses memory and not releasing it properly.

I would like to hear your opinions regarding why my app constantly dying when there is 50+mb of free memory and why AWS metrics show different result comparing to java tools

Comment: Java applications can also allocate native memory which is not part of any heap, stack space, etc. For example `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` or native libraries used from Java, memory for Java itself, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm aware of that. But we are not dealing with buffers as well as files. Also 100MB seems to be enough to deal with for any native library etc

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope GC configs are default(Specs: openjdk 8, debian OS)

Comment: were you able to understand this problem i am having the same issue with nodejs

Comment: @Liran not really, we figured out that since latest java 8 release or java 9+ there is flags to automatically handle memory inside the docker, its became a bit better since then

Comment: @BohdanZ. i was able to solve my problem with a better design,
instead of streaming to memory all my data ( which can not scale ) 
i stream my data to response stream of an http response 
now my memory footprint is nothing and i can handle a lot of calls, i would suggest you try to do the same if you can, if you need some more assistants let me know