# JVM in a container always using maximum ram percentage

Tags: java, docker, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

I have the following VM Options:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
```

As stated earlier, this JVM runs inside a docker container. Memory allocation to the pod is managed by Kubernetes. If I assign 10 GB to the pod, the committed heap is 8GB, 20GB then 16GB is committed, but what I see is that the heap used is around 2.5 GB. Moreover, the 8GB or 16GB committed heap is from the very beginning of the application's run.

Any ideas how to keep it around the 2.5 GB (used) + some free space to allow for expansion?

Comment: `-Xms2500M -Xmx8G`

Comment: using explicit mem flags also yields the same behavior .. the committed heap space is 5GB

Comment: Are you sure that you didn’t specify other, contradicting options?

Comment: There are no other vm options except ones related to new relic

Comment: How do you monitor the amount of committed heap? What are the values for used and committed heap right after the start?  How long after the start did you take the last measurement? Which JDK and OS do you use?

Comment: Seems like existing issue while running Java application in Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595468/why-docker-java-app-is-getting-killed-because-of-memory

Comment: @Juraj Martinka Monitored via https://newrelic.com/ it has a nice option to see all your running JVMs and see each's memory usage & size accordingly. The monitoring starts from the first second

Comment: @EbramSherif so you say your app consumes 2.5 GB right after the start - what kind of processing are you doing that the heap allocation is so large from the very first second? You also didn't mention the OS and JDK version you use.